# Volume in a scattering process equal to 1?

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, phase-space, fermis-golden-rule

I'm studying Fermi's golden rule, and in section 8.3.1 of "Braibant, Giacomelli, Spurio - Particles and Fundamental Interactions" there is an application to the decay of the neutron. While calculating the density of final states
$$\dfrac{dN}{dE_0}$$
it says, in phase space, that this can be calculated considering (for a single particle)
$$dN=\dfrac{dxdydzdp_xdp_ydp_z}{h^3}$$
Then, integrating to add app all possible final states, the terms $dxdydz$ gives the volume of the system.

**The book then puts the volume equal to 1, without giving any explanation**. Why is that?

My hypothesis is that the volume is absorbed in the matrix element $|M_{if}|^2$ that appears in Fermi's golden rule, but Why can we do that? Isn't that volume infinite in principle?

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to consider a unit volume.

Comment: @Triatticus Do you mean, they considered the decay happening in a box of volume 1?

Comment: Yeah it's just a guess unfortunately so I can't with any certainty say why.